# Jquery Cycle Plugin Pause/Resume Toggle?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I've found a few questions/answers for this but I have had difficulty figuring out the answers and implementing them into my own Cycle slide show.  I managed to find the following as a solution and it seems to be the simplest solution I've found so far:

```
<button id="pauseToggle">Pause</button>

$('#pauseToggle').click(function() {
    var slideshow = $( '.cycle-slideshow' );
    if ( slideshow.is( '.cycle-paused' ) ) {
    slideshow.cycle( 'resume' );
    $(this).text( 'Pause' );
    }
    else {
        slideshow.cycle( 'pause' );
        $(this).text( 'Play' );
    }
);
```

But I can't make 100% sense of what's what.  I know that the first part is for the actual button and is placed where the button is to show up on the page, and then I see the button's id reference as well but I'm not sure what else is what.  I understand the basic idea of if and else statements and I can sort of see what's going on but as far as the references and labels, well I really only need to know what they are for.  I don't need a long detailed explanation, just a short and sweet summary for the following:

- var slideshow
- .cycle-slideshow
- .cycle-paused
- slideshow.cycle

With that, I can figure this out for sure, even if I have to go back to Google, I'll have a much better idea of what I'm googling for :)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this one out as well by doing some tedious Googling, so I'll be adding the solution here to help out others...

The solution I found is not an if,else statement, but rather it hides the play button and pause button appropriately.

```
 $('#bannernav').click(function() {
      $('#promobanner').cycle('pause');
      $('#play').show();
      $('#pause').hide();
 });
```

My slideshow's id is '#promobanner' and the id of, '#bannernav', is for the pager links.  This bit here causes the slideshow to Pause if any of the pager links are clicked, and then shows the id of, '#play', while hiding the id of, '#pause'.  I actually tried to target the anchor tags inside the '#bannernav' but it wouldn't work at all this way.  I'm unsure why it wouldn't work, but this solution doesn't cause any problems that I can foresee.  I then did the exact same thing for the "Right" and "Left" navigational links so that if you click "Next slide" or, "Previous slide" it will Pause as well and hide the Pause button.

```
$('#play').hide();
```

This sets it up so that the '#play' id is initially hidden.

```
$('#play').click( function(e){
      $('#promobanner').cycle('resume');
      $('#play').hide();
      $('#pause').show();
  });
```

This portion defines what happens when you click on the id of, '#play'.  It will resume the slide show with the id, '#promobanner' and then hide the id, '#play' but show the id, '#pause'.  So now, as the slide show resumes, the Pause button is the only button being shown.

```
 $('#pause').click( function(e){
      $('#promobanner').cycle('pause');
      $('#play').show();
      $('#pause').hide();
  });
```

Finally, this portion defines what happens when you click on the id of, '#pause'.  It will pause the slide show with the id, '#promobanner' and then hide the id, '#pause' but show the id, '#play'.  The slideshow will be paused, and the Play button is the only button being shown.

I hope this helps someone out.  It's not exactly the solution I was looking for, but it seems to do the trick! :)